# Clone content JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found some code, I modified the same but now I want to clone the content that i type in the input from the original div in cloned elements

```
<button type="button" id="addmore" >Add More</button>
<button type="button" id="rmvbtn" >Remove</button>


 <div class="dynamic-wrapper">
  <div class="datagrid">
    <table>
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
            <th>UM</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td><p><strong>1</strong></p>
    </td>
    <td>
 <div class="dynamic-row">
                <input type="text" name="chpob1" id="chpob1" />
        </div>        
    </td>    
</tr>

 </tbody>
 </table></div></div>
```

The Jquery is here !

http://jsfiddle.net/MetCastle/6uhQt/

Hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Can you post the jQuery here?

Comment: Not really sure what you want to do here...

Comment: I want to clone the info that I type in the input without lost the autoincrement in the name and id of the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var increment = 2;//First clone line number

$('#addmore').on('click', function(){
    var original = $('.dynamic-row:eq( 0 )').closest('tr');
     var cloneDiv = original.clone();
    //Increment line number
    $('strong', cloneDiv).html(increment++);
    original.closest('table').append(cloneDiv);
});

$('#rmvbtn').on('click', function(){       
    if(increment > 2){
        $('.dynamic-row:last').closest('tr').remove();
        //decrease line number
        increment--;
    }
    });

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5kv9/2/)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I talking about but how can for autoincrement the value just the original post? 
I add your line to the original #rmvbtn and with that avoid delete the original.

Comment: I see... I've edited my answer, now its fully featured and working as a charm. Would mind to accept the answer?

Comment: As you said: Works like a charm!
Thank you for your prompt response !